# Help with Displaying Magento Attributes on product page

Tags: product, attributes

I would like to highlight some of my product attributes on the Product View page. 
The following code works for the first attribute (operating_system) but not the second.
What could be the cause of this:

```
    <?php if($_product->getoperating_system()): ?><li><?php $os=$_product->getAttributeText('operating_system');
$osid=$_product->getoperating_system();
 echo '<a href="/catalogsearch/advanced/result/?operating_system%5B%5D='.str_replace(' ', '_',$osid).'"><img class="specicon" src="/media/avenueimages/icons/'.str_replace(' ', '_',$os).'.png" alt="'.$os.'" title="'.$os.'"></a><p>'.$os.'</p>' ;?></li><?php endif; ?>
<?php if($_product->getinternal_memory()): ?><li><?php $imem=$_product->getAttributeText('internal_memory');
$imemid=$_product->getinternal_memory();
 echo '<img class="specicon" src="/media/avenueimages/icons/memory.png" alt="'.$imem.'" title="'.$imem.'"></a><p>'.$imem.'</p>' ;?></li><?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: what are the attribute types and attribute code for both the attributes?

Comment: Both are drop down

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For your second attribute your are not using the correct default getter format. Use it as below:

```
$imemid=$_product->getInternalMemory();
```

For any attribute you need to use first letter as capital and remove underscore (*) and capitalize the letter right after the underscore (*)

Comment: Actually `getinternal_memory()` works as well but don't tell anybody, this is a side effect, not the intended usage, and should never ever be used.